# password_verify no devuelve true

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, php7

Buen dia Estimados, he intentado varias cosas y no obtuve resultado positivo, por eso recurro a ustedes. Como dice el titulo, y aclaro que ya probe poner la longitud en 255, tambien probe cambiar el tipo de la columna password a text y nada, cambie el cotejamiento, borre la tabla, la volvi a generar y sigo sin poder hacer funcionar la bendita funcion password_verify, estoy trabajando con PHP 7. Les dejo el formato de mi tabla

[image: Tabla]
[image: Datos]

Aqui dejo el form con el login

```
<?php  
require_once('controladores/funciones.php');
$user = "";
$password = "";
if(!empty($_POST)) :
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
        //Login Usuario
        loginUser($_POST);
    
    endif;
   
?>

<form action="" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-info">Ingresar</button>
                                </div>
```

Aqui abajo les dejo la funcion Login

```
function loginUser($datos){
        try{
            $usuario = $datos['user'];
            $password = $datos['password'];
            $contador = 0;
            $pdo = conexion();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario or email = :usuario";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute((array(":usuario"=>$usuario)));
            while($registro=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                
                if(password_verify($password, $registro['password'])){
                     $contador++;
                }
        }
       
        if($contador>0){
               header('Location: loginCorrecto.php'); 
            }else { 
                echo "<h1>Las contraseñas no coinciden</h1><br>";
            }
             $pdo = null;
        }
            
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
            }
    }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Comprobaciones básicas: 1.- Las variables $usuario y $password no deben estar vacías. 2.- ¿ `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` devuleve al menos un resultado?

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué guardas en `$registro['password']`? Como te sugiere @BaruchSpinoza ¿haces validación de haber recibido el password?

Comment: Estás comparando el valor contra sí mismo: `if(password_verify($password, $registro['password'])){` ahí, `$password` es lo mismo que `$registro['password']`, si observas bien en tu código más arriba: `$password = $datos['password'];`. Tienes que sacar la otra password a comparar leyendo los resultados del `SELECT`. Otra, cosa, supongo que hiciste un hash al momento de insertar la password.

Comment: Hola, no estoy comparando el mismo valor, registro['password'], trae el valor de la base y $password trae el valor del post. Ya realice var_dump y ambas variables muestran correctamente, una muestra lo que trae el post y la otra muestra lo que levanta de la consulta sql..

Comment: @A.Cedano Te corrijo: **$password** no es lo mismo que **$registro['password']** nota que en el **while** esta convirtiendo lo que viene en su consulta en un **array asociativo** por lo que **$registro** es un arreglo asociativo de su consulta.

Comment: Ok, perdonen ustedes, me confundí analizando el código @NikolaTesla y Guillermo. ¿Podrias confirmar entonces que realmente guardaste un hash al momento de insertar?, dinos también de qué tipo y qué tamaño tiene la columna `password` en la tabla.

Comment: No hay problema @A.Cedano, si, esta guardado correctamente, podes ver en la imagen que adjunte arriba que el password se guarda hasheado. Aca adjunto solo una parte de la funcion que guarda los registros.
//Funcion registrar
//$datos viene del post tambien
```
 $password = password_hash($datos['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $query ->bindValue(':password',$password);
 $query->execute();
```

Comment: @A.Cedano No te preocupes para eso estamos en este foro para aprender mas, de hecho es lo que le decia al usuario en mi respuesta.

Comment: Según lo que has indicado hasta ahora todo parece correcto. Lo único que me suena raro es el cotejamiento en tu columna `password`, asumiento que todavía es una tabla de prueba, sugiero que cambies **el cotejamiento de esa columna a `utf8_general_ci`** y pruebes si funciona. Otra cosa es que conviene que limpies el dato antes de hacer el `hash` para insertar. Por ejemplo, que no tenga espacios en blanco al principio, al final, etc. Supongo que tienes cuidado de la codificación en el contexto, de modo que no se estén produciendo caracteres inesperados en el flujo.

Comment: Ahi probe cambiar el cotejamiento pero sigue sin funcionar. Es mas probe crear otro usuario con la contraseña hasheada y que la misma sea solo un numero y no hay caso. Como vos decis, no veo nada raro en el codigo, hago var_dump y devuelve los mismos valores tanto que ingreso como el de mysql, entonces estimo que la cuestion tiene que estar cuando hace la comparacion

Comment: Sugiero más cosas: 1. Al insertar el hash Indica en `bindValue()` el tipo de dato (string); 2. Prueba creando hash desde contraseñas alfanuméricas. Si 1 y 2 sigue sin funcionar, 3. Intenta usar `bindParam()` en la inserción, indicando el tipo de dato.

Comment: @A.Cedano despues de tanto mirar, era un problema de sintaxis, estaba hasheando la contraseña en 2 funciones y por eso nunca coincidia, en la 2da funcion le saque el hasheo y listo! Te agradezco mucho por todas las sugerencias lo mismo que a Nikola. Un abrazo grande.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Recuerda que **password_verify()** compara un String con un hash ejemplo:

```
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('micontraseñaesmuyfacil', $hash)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}
```

2.- Te dejo un enlace para que puedas ver como funciona **password_verify()**

[password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Hola Nikola, si, he visto ejemplos sobre como funciona password_verify, hago otra aclaracion que las contraseñas almacenadas son numericas, nose si influye en algo, no deberia.

Comment: Claro que influye, lo que quiero decir es que antes de almacenar tus contraseñas deberias de hacerles un **hash** hay muchos metodos para realizar esta accion, te dejo un enlace para que profundices mas en el tema: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php de lo contrario no podras utilizar  **password_verify()** si ya leiste la documentacion veras que necesita forzosamente un hash para poderlo comparar con tu string.

Comment: Yo asumí que sí está guardando las contraseñas hasheadas puesto que menciona haber cambiado la longitud del campo que las almacena en la base de datos

Comment: Nikola, ahi adjunte como estoy guardando la contraseña, la misma esta hasheada, esto tambien se puede ver en la imagen que subi. Lo que me es raro que probe borrar la tabla tambien y nada, no tiene mucho misterio esta funcion, hasta probe poner la contraseña manualmente de la siguiente manera en esta linea if(password_verify('password a mano', $registro['password'])) y tampoco funciona.